Using SDFormat for development after Gz-Garden is installed causes SDFormat install issues
I am trying to understand how to work with the SDFormat (specifically libsdformat-dev) Ubuntu package while also having Gazebo Garden installed locally. Gazebo Garden relies on the package libsdformat12-12, which does not include the development headers (as its not a dev package): https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/amd64/libsdformat12-12/filelist
Along with that, because libsdformat12-12 is a specific version of SDFormat, trying to installed libsdformat-dev conflicts with the package:

> sudo apt install -y libsdformat-dev
...

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsdformat12 : Breaks: libsdformat12-12 but 12.3.0+ds-2 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  apt: command [apt-get install -y libsdformat-dev] failed
  apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [libsdformat-dev]


I am on Ubuntu 22.04 and installed the gz-garden package.
Any clue how to get around this issue?
